# Why does Spring require the name of the enum param same as the string value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I created a Spring boot app which takes an enum parameter `client` in the header. If I define the enum Client as follows:

```
public enum Client {

  app("app"),
  web("web");

  Client( String agent){
    this.agent = agent;
  }

  public final String agent;
}
```

it works successfully. But when I declare my enum as follows:

```
public enum Client {

  APP("app"),
  WEB("web");

  Client( String agent){
    this.agent = agent;
  }

  public final String agent;
}
```

it throws the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.xx.xxx.Client.app` .

It seems that Spring is trying to convert the string parameter into the enum of the same name, but why is it not using the `Client.valueOf(String)` method to derive the `Client` enum ?

I can declare my enum as in the first approach but wanted to understand why Spring shows this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you have given and the error message you are getting, I think you have mistaken The enum constant with the enum value.

```
 APP("app")
```

Here, APP is the enum constant and app is its value, so when you call

```
Client.valueOf("APP")
```

It will Return - "app".

But here as the error suggests, you are calling

```
Client.valueOf("app")
```

Comment: well, then the concern is why is Spring creating the enum with the constant rather than the value?

Comment: Well, first of all Spring has nothing to do with this. I think there's a misunderstanding here about how to access the value of an Enum. If you can elaborate what you really want to do, it will be easier to help.

Comment: I want to be able to separate the controller layer param value from the name of the Enum constant.